# SQL - Oracle Functions using variables for schema names

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am writing some oracle stored procedures where we have conditional logic which effects which schema we are working from and I am not sure how to do this in the sql for the stored proc.  If I am working with prepared statements then its fine but in the scenario where I am just executing a query to say populate another variable then I dont know how to do this.  For example

```
PROCEDURE register (
    incustomer_ref  in  VARCHAR2,
    incustomer_type in  VARCHAR2,
    outreturn_code  out VARCHAR2
)
IS
    customer_schema varchar2(30);
         record_exists number(1);
BEGIN
    if incustomer_type='a' then
        customer_schema:='schemaA';
    elsif incustomer_type='b' then
        customer_schema:='schemaB';
    end if;


    --This type of command I cant get to work
    select count(*) into record_exists from **customer_schema**.customer_registration where customer_ref=incustomer_ref

    --but a  statement like this i know how to do
    if record_exists = 0 then
        execute immediate 'insert into '||customer_schema||'.customer_registration   
        values ('||incustomer_ref||','Y',sysdate)';
    end if;
```

Can anyone shine some light on what I am missing here.
Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use execute immediate also for select statment:

```
    execute immediate    'select count(*)  from '|| customer_schema 
                      || '.customer_registration where customer_ref= :b1' 
     into record_exists using incustomer_ref;
```

Comment: +1 - didn't know about the `INTO` or `USING` clauses of `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Thanks!

Comment: I too didnt realise you could do it.  Thanks for the help.